# List clusters in IBM ICP v3

Tags: ibm-cloud-private

In IBM Cloud Private version 2, bx pr cluster command lists all the clusters in the account. What is the command to list the clusters in IBM Cloud Private version3?

Comment: Maybe research somewhere like https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IBM Cloud Private 3.x.x and onward uses `cloudctl` instead of `bx pr` for Command Line Interface (CLI). You may find documentation in the IBM Cloud Private Knowledge Center (KC) here (ICP 3.1.0 selected): https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSBS6K_3.1.0/manage_cluster/icp_cli.html